# SparkR - Creating Test and Train DataFrames for Data Mining

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, sparkr

I wish to partition a SparkR DataFrame into two subsets, one for training and one for testing of a glim.

My normal way of doing this in R is to create an array index of the rows, sample the array into a new array, and then subset the data based on the rows being in or not in the subset. e.g.

```
seed=42 # of course
index <- 1:nrow(df) # sample works on vectors
trainindex <- sample(index, trunc(length(index)/2)) # split data set into two
train <- df[trainindex, ] # training data set
test <- df[-trainindex, ] # all the records not in the training data set
```

This approach appears to not be applicable in SparkR DataFrames as the rows are not uniquely addressable as they are in R.

As partitioning of the data set is a fundamental technique to data mining, has anyone developed an approach to randomly partitioning the rows of a DataFrame?

Building on this idea, I seem to be continually switching backwards and forwards between R data.frames and Spark DataFrames as I work.  It seems undesirable to fill up memory with multiple copies of similar data frames.  Does anyone have good advice for a general approach on use of SparkR DataFrames for a data mining project?  For example, perform all the tasks up to stage X using R data.frames, then switch to Spark DataFrames?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer to the first part of my question (the second part is taking a little longer).  For those who follow...

`sdfData <- createDataFrame(sqlContext, index)`
`train <- sample(sdfData, withReplacement=FALSE, fraction=0.5, seed=42)`
`test <- except(sdfData, train)`

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your first question: since Spark 2.0.0, you can use `randomSplit`:

```
sdfData <- createDataFrame(sqlContext, index)
trainTest <-randomSplit(rfData,c(0.7,0.3), seed)
train = trainTest[[1]]
test = trainTest[[2]]
```